# get JSON data that matches the value of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array that populates when an element's checkbox is ticked.

I am trying to find the value of each array object, match its value with data in a JSON array and spit out a list of details for each object.

JSON LIKE THIS -->

```
var info = [{
        "id": 0,
       "name": "Band1",
       "genre": "metal",
       "stage": "stage-1",
       "time": "13:00",
        "year": 1996  
},
{
 "id": 1,
       "name": "Band2",
       "genre": "metal",
       "stage": "stage-1",
       "time": "13:50",
        "year": 1996
},
{
 "id": 2,
       "name": "Band3",
       "genre": "metal",
       "stage": "stage-2",
       "time": "14:40",
        "year": 1996
},
```

The JS is like this...
the stage page has a list of bands with checkboxes.. you check a band and it gets outputted in the schedule page in a list.... this is what i want to acheieve.

The bands, when checked, are being pushed into the array fine.. I just cant get the list to work on the schedule page.

```
 $( document ).ready( function(){

   var selectedChk=[]; 
    var checkboxArray = new Array();
   localStorage["selectedChk"] = JSON.stringify(selectedChk);
    var stage_img;
    var infoview = "";
    var stage_choice;

    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#stage-page", function () {

            var li = "";
            $.each(info, function (i, name) {
                    if(name.stage === stage_choice){
                     console.log(name);
                            li += '<li><p class="time-slot">'+ name.time +'</p><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + name.name + ' <br/> <span class="a-genre">'+ name.genre +'</span></a><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="band" value="' + i + '" id=' + i + '></li>';
                    }
            });
            $("#stage-list").html(li).promise().done(function () {
                    $(this).listview("refresh");
            });


            //when page loads check checkboxes
             $(".checkbox").each(function() {
               if(selectedChk.indexOf(this.value)> -1 ){
                    $(this).attr('checked','checked');
               }
             });


            $(".checkbox").click(function(){
                    //if ($(this).is(':checked')){      
                    checkboxArray = $(".checkbox:checked").map(function() {
                            return this.value;

                    });   //code


               console.log(selectedChk);
                    //loop through all checkboxes
                     console.log("selected check  "+selectedChk);
                    $(".checkbox").each(function() {
                            //if its checked
                             console.log("index of  "+selectedChk.indexOf(this.value));
                            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                            {
                                    //see if it is in the array
                                    if (selectedChk.indexOf(this.value)> -1) {
                                             //its in the array do nothing
                                    }else{
                                            //add it
                                            selectedChk.push(this.value);
                                    }     //code  
                            }else{
                                    //its not checked
                                   console.log("its not checked");
                                    if (selectedChk.indexOf(this.value)!==-1) {
                                             //its in the array
                                             //we need to remove it
                                             var pos = selectedChk.indexOf(this.value);
                                             selectedChk.splice(pos,1);

                                    }else{
                                           //do nothing
                                    }     //  
                            }

                    });   //code
                    console.log("selected checkbox "+selectedChk);
                    //console.log(checkboxArray);
              //look local storage
            //}
            })
    });



     **$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#schedule-page", function (e) {  
        var li = "";
         $.each(selectedChk, function (key,value) {        


HERE IS WHERE I AM TRYING TO GET JSON DATA THAT MATCHES THE VALUE FROM THE SELECTEDCHK ARRAY.. AND THEN PUT IT IN LI


         });

      $("#schedule-list").html(li).promise().done(function () {
                    $(this).listview("refresh");
        });
});**
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think it might help if you add more details.  What's your code to grab the values of the checkboxes?  And what's your json object code you're trying to match it with?  Chances is are you want a for(key in jsonObj){} loop. And if(jsonObj[key] === checkboxVal){ console.log('match'); }

Comment: Can you post the json?

Comment: Please post an example of your data, the value you are trying to find and the result you want to get.

Comment: So basically its for a band app.. the stage page has a list of bands with checkboxes.. you check a band and gets outputted in the schedule page in a list... this is what im trying to achieve

I've left the unnecessary bits out .. thanks all.